# How to get the sum from the loop? (php)

Tags: php, loops, if-statement, while-loop, sum

Can anybody help me to get the sum or total of the `$total_h` in the below loop?
I just need to display the sum of $total_h after the loop has finished so I'll know how many hours I've worked.

```
 <?php

  $get_time = mysql_query("select * from tbl_timekeep where emp_id = 
                                   'OJT0125' order by date desc");

  while ($fect_time = mysql_fetch_array($get_time))
   {
       if ($fect_time[3] == '----' || $fect_time[3] == 'No Out')
          {
          $out = '17:00:00';
          }
       else
          {
          $out = $fect_time[3];
          }

   $from = new DateTime($fect_time[2]);
   $to = new DateTime($out);
   $total_h = $from->diff($to)->format('%h.%i');``
   echo $fect_time[2].'to'.$fect_time[3]." = [ $total_h ]<br>";

  }

  ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     <?php

    $get_time = mysql_query("select * from tbl_timekeep where emp_id = 
                               'OJT0125' order by date desc");
        $sum_total_h = 0;
       while ($fect_time = mysql_fetch_array($get_time))
          {
          if ($fect_time[3] == '----' || $fect_time[3] == 'No Out')
          {
           $out = '17:00:00';
           }
      else
         {
         $out = $fect_time[3];
         }

      $from = new DateTime($fect_time[2]);
      $to = new DateTime($out);
      $total_h = $from->diff($to)->format('%h.%i');``

      $sum_total_h +=$total_h;
      echo $fect_time[2].'to'.$fect_time[3]." = [ $total_h ]<br>";
      }
      echo $sum_total_h;

      ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

add a code to sum up the $total_h;

```
$sum_total_h = 0;//initialize
```

then after you get the $total_h. you have to add this code.

```
$sum_total_h +=$total_h;
```

Then after the loop is done you can echo the sum of $total_h

```
echo $sum_total_h;
```

Comment: This one's the same with the 1st answer :) Thank you!

Comment: Actually I am the first to answer the question. He just apply it to your code. To make the story short..He just copy my answer.

Comment: Sorry sir, but I need to have 15 reputations for me to vote up. I'm new here, I registered for like an hour ago. So yea. :(